# How can I stop the empty "ghost" cells in a table view from dynamically resizing alongside custom cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using the typical method of dynamically sizing table view cells that contain text views in them:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

This works just fine for the cells I actually instantiate and use, but it has a strange side effect: the empty cells that the table view shows below instantiated cells end up resizing their height alongside whichever custom cell I'm currently editing.

So when I input three, four, or more lines of text into a newly added custom cell...

- ...all the other prototype-based custom cells already filled in the
  table remain unchanged
- ...the custom cell being edited resizes dynamically as intended
- ...but all the "ghost" cells below the last custom cell in the table
  view end up dynamically expanding alongside the custom cell that's
  being edited

My first thought was that it must have something to do with how I dequeue cells, and specifically what I return when dequeueing doesn't happen:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
            return myCell
        } else {
            return CustomCell()
        }
}
```

But I tried returning both my custom cell and just `UITableViewCell()` in the `else` block and the result is the same.

Does anyone know why this could possibly be happening and/or how to get around it?

Comment: What about removing those empty cells? I'm not sure about their height, but you can remove them by setting empty `UIView` object to `UITableView`'s `tableFooterView` or `tableFooterView`.

Comment: 'tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()' . U can try like this ?

Comment: what does your cell contain? I guess due to the autolayout the empty cells will be having some basic default constraints which leads to resizing the cells according to those constraints in the cell.

Comment: In prepareForReuse of UITableViewCell subclass, nil out the label text.